# Laravel 5 confirmation error message display in wrong field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I would like to check if there is an error in my code I did not realize but why is my confirmation field's error message keep on displaying in the wrong filed? Suppose I have a password field and a password_confirmation field, but every time when user made a mistake in the password_confirmation field, the error displays in the password field instead. Here is a screenshot of the error.

[image: invalid error message display]

And here is how I validate the input using FormRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
    'login_email'           =>  'required',
    'g-recaptcha-response'  =>  'required|captcha',
    ];

    if ($this->request->has('password'))
    {
        $rules = [
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|between:6,200',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response'  =>  'required|captcha',
        ];
    }

    if ($this->request->has('old_password'))
    {
        $rules = [
        'old_password' => 'required|between:6,200',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|between:6,200',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response'  =>  'required|captcha',
        ];
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Finally this is my html code

```
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal login-form', 'url' => URL::route('postReset'), 'method' => 'POST')) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    {!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'New Password*')); !!}
                    {!! MessagerService::setInlineError($errors->first('password')) !!}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Retype New Password*')); !!}
                    {!! MessagerService::setInlineError($errors->first('password_confirmation')) !!}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    {!! app('captcha')->display(); !!}
                    {!! MessagerService::setInlineError($errors->first('g-recaptcha-response')) !!}
                </div>
            </div>                  

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary cbtn-login">Reset Password</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="{{ Session::get('hash') }}">
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: where  from you get this class? `MessagerService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have defined **confirmed** rule for your **password** field, all the errors related to password_confirmation will also be shown in password field.

Comment: what should i do in this case? i could not change the confirmed rule to password_confirmation field or else it would not validate.

Comment: you should take out the "the password confirmation does not match" from list of password errors and show it in password_confirmation field.